# How to Simplify Yule Walker Expression for AR Coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, stochastic-processes, systems-of-equations

We have an AR(2) process (w/ intercept omitted):
$$
y _ { t } = a _ { 1 } y _ { t - 1 } + a _ { 2 } y _ { t - 2 } + \varepsilon _ { t }
$$
We multiply the second order equation by $ y_{t-s} \text{ for } s = 0, s = 1, s = 2 \ldots $
$$
\begin{aligned} E y _ { t } y _ { t } & = a _ { 1 } E y _ { t - 1 } y _ { t } + a _ { 2 } E y _ { t - 2 } y _ { t } + E \varepsilon _ { t } y _ { t } \\ E y _ { t } y _ { t - 1 } & = a _ { 1 } E y _ { t - 1 } y _ { t - 1 } + a _ { 2 } E y _ { t - 2 } y _ { t - 1 } + E \varepsilon _ { t } y _ { t - 1 } \\ E y _ { t } y _ { t - 2 } & = a _ { 1 } E y _ { t - 1 } y _ { t - 2 } + a _ { 2 } E y _ { t - 2 } y _ { t - 2 } + E \varepsilon _ { t } y _ { t - 2 } \\ \cdots & \\ & \cdots \\ E y _ { t } y _ { t - s } & = a _ { 1 } E y _ { t - 1 } y _ { t - s } + a _ { 2 } E y _ { t - 2 } y _ { t - s } + E \varepsilon _ { t } y _ { t - s } \end{aligned}
$$

By definition, the autocovariances of a stationary series are such that $E y _ { t } y _ { t - s } =$
$E y _ { t - s } y _ { t } = E y _ { t - k } y _ { t - k - s } = \gamma _ { s } .$ We also know that $E \varepsilon _ { t } y _ { t } = \sigma ^ { 2 }$ and $E \varepsilon _ { t } y _ { t - s } = 0 .$ Hence, we
can use the equations in $( 2.24 )$ to form

$$
\gamma _ { 0 } = a _ { 1 } \gamma _ { 1 } + a _ { 2 } \gamma _ { 2 } + \sigma ^ { 2 }
$$
$$
\begin{aligned} \gamma _ { 1 } & = a _ { 1 } \gamma _ { 0 } + a _ { 2 } \gamma _ { 1 } \\ \gamma _ { s } & = a _ { 1 } \gamma _ { s - 1 } + a _ { 2 } \gamma _ { s - 2 } \\ \text { Dividing by } \gamma _ { 0 } \text { yields } \\ \rho _ { 1 } & = a _ { 1 } \rho _ { 0 } + a _ { 2 } \rho _ { 1 } \\ \rho _ { s } & = a _ { 1 } \rho _ { s - 1 } + a _ { 2 } \rho _ { s - 2 } \end{aligned}
$$

**Question: How did $ \gamma_1 / \gamma_0 $ turn into the $\rho_1$ function?**

**The simple algebra of this division isn't making sense. What happens to the Variance $ \sigma^2 $ that's in $ \gamma_0 $ but somehow eliminated in the $ \gamma_1$ function?**

Comment: You forgot the 1st line with $\gamma 0$

Comment: @Damien I think it's there? Just above the line for $ \gamma_{1} $ and centered. Maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes this line. Don't forget it!

Comment: I realized the first small caveat that helps me solve the problem. $E \varepsilon _ { t } y _ { t } = \sigma^2 $ but this has to be 0 to eliminate serial correlation.

Comment: What do you mean with eliminate ? This term is very inportant ...

Comment: How would you describe it @Damien ?

Comment: No time now but please note that Wikipedia is very detailed on this matter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have an AR$(2)$ process

$$X_t=\frac{1}{3}X_{t-1}+\frac{1}{2}X_{t-2}+Z_t$$

From properties of the lag operator:

$$L(B)=1-\frac{1}{3}B-\frac{1}{2}B^2$$

This has real roots, both are outside the unit circle. This implies this process is weakly stationary.

> **Remark:** A stochastic process is said to be weakly stationary when its *mean* and *autocovariance* does not vary with respect to *time*. Also,
>   the second moment is finite at all times. For more details see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process)

Next multiply both sides by $X_{t-k}$ and take expectation to obtain $E(X_{t-k}X_t)=\gamma(k)$. (**now the part you are interested in**). Since $\mu=0$, assuming $\gamma(k)=0$, then:

$$\gamma(-k)=\frac{1}{3}\gamma(-k+1)+\frac{1}{2}\gamma(-k+2)$$

Here note $\gamma(k)=\gamma(-k)$ for any $k$.

$$\gamma(k)=\frac{1}{3}\gamma(k-1)+\frac{1}{2}\gamma(k-2)$$

Dividing both sides by $\gamma(0)=\sigma^2$ gives:

$$\rho(k)=\frac{1}{3}\rho(k-1)+\frac{1}{2}\rho(k-2)$$

**Notice $Var(X)=(E(X))^2-E(XY)$. See the above assumption and for stationary time series $E(X)=\mu=0$**. The definition of autocorrelation is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation).

*The example is from the course by the state university of New York*

Comment: Thanks a ton for this! Are you assuming this process is white noise? Hence why you're able to define $\mu = \frac { 1 } { 3 } \mu + \frac { 1 } { 2 } \mu$ as being 0? Or is this an assumption for stationarity? I would think the former?

Comment: No, see the update.

Comment: $$
\begin{array} { l } { E \left( y _ { t } \right) = E \left( y _ { t - s } \right) = \mu } \\ { E \left[ \left( y _ { t } - \mu \right) ^ { 2 } \right] = E \left[ \left( y _ { t - s } - \mu \right) ^ { 2 } \right] = \sigma _ { y } ^ { 2 } } \end{array}
$$ and $$
E \left[ \left( y _ { t } - \mu \right) \left( y _ { t - s } - \mu \right) \right] = E \left[ \left( y _ { t - j } - \mu \right) \left( y _ { t - j - s } - \mu \right) \right] = \gamma _ { s }
$$. Where $ \mu, \sigma^2, \gamma_s $ constant. But how does that make $ \mu = 0 $ from your equation?

Comment: This below equation: $$
\mu = \frac { 1 } { 3 } \mu + \frac { 1 } { 2 } \mu = 0
$$

Comment: $\mu=0$, because of the roots of the characteristic equation. I will remove this bit. I think its causing confusion. Just read the Remark

Comment: I think I understand. Since we don't have a unit root process it's convergent. But for $ \mu = 0 $ it must mean the process is such that $$
y _ { t } = a _ { 0 } + a _ { 1 } y _ { t - 1 } + \varepsilon _ { t }
$$ where $ \epsilon_t = \text{ white noise } $. And white noise meaning mean is 0.

Comment: Yes, here $\epsilon_t$ is indeed white noise. Upvote :)

Comment: Sorry to beat a dead horse. But in your construction of $$
\gamma ( - k ) = \frac { 1 } { 3 } \gamma ( - k + 1 ) + \frac { 1 } { 2 } \gamma ( - k + 2 )
$$ what are you doing to bring in this (-k), (-k+1), (-k+2) into the function? (k-1), (k-2).. makes sense in that I see it's in the function. Or is it for abitrary for easier exposition?

Comment: When you consider $\gamma(k)=E(X_{t-k},X_t)$ for the given time series you get $\gamma(-k)$, which is equal to $\gamma(k)$. There is a lot of material available on the web regarding Time series modelling; you may find that helpful.